# XML to XSLT Tranformation using Namespace not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I have the following XML and I am able to transform and grouping as per my expected output, but when I tried to use with namespace xmlns="http://oracle.com/SGGIMDsEvents" but never worked. 
Following xml sample input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrdersRoot xmlns="http://oracle.com/SGGIMDsEvents">
  <Order dateTimeTagFormat="xsd">
      <level>
        <OrderID>O1</OrderID>
        <ItemID>I1</ItemID>
        <TrackingID>T1</TrackingID>
    </level>
  </Order>
  <Order dateTimeTagFormat="xsd">
    <level>
        <OrderID>O1</OrderID>
        <ItemID>I2</ItemID>
        <TrackingID>T2</TrackingID>
    </level>
  </Order>
  <Order dateTimeTagFormat="xsd">
    <level>
        <OrderID>O1</OrderID>
        <ItemID>I2</ItemID>
        <TrackingID>T3</TrackingID>
    </level>
  </Order>
  <Order dateTimeTagFormat="xsd">
    <level>
        <OrderID>O2</OrderID>
        <ItemID>I3</ItemID>
        <TrackingID>T4</TrackingID>
    </level>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <level>
        <OrderID>O2</OrderID>
        <ItemID>I3</ItemID>
        <TrackingID>T5</TrackingID>
    </level>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <level>>
        <OrderID>O3</OrderID>
        <ItemID>I4</ItemID>
        <TrackingID>T6</TrackingID>
  </level>
  </Order>
</OrdersRoot>
```

XSLT Code  - some parts are commented just for namespace testing otherwise it is working fine here is a link to run this code 
URL without Namespace - https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhDDyC/3 
URL with Namespace - https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhDDyC/5

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:t="http://oracle.com/SGGIMDsEvents" 
xmlns="http://oracle.com/SGGIMDsEvents" 
exclude-result-prefixes="t" 
version="1.0" 

>

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

<!-- Create a key to match against groups in source schema -->
<xsl:key name="k1" match="t:Order/t:level" use="t:OrderID"/>

<!--<xsl:key name="k2" match="Order/level" use="concat(OrderID,'|',ItemID)"/>-->

<!--<xsl:key name="k3" match="Order/level" use="concat(OrderID,'|',ItemID,'|',TrackingID)"/>-->

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="/t:OrdersRoot" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/t:OrdersRoot">
    <orders>

      <!-- This will loop through our key ("OrderID") -->
      <xsl:for-each select="t:Order/level[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('k1',t:OrderID))]">

        <order>
          <orderid>
            <xsl:value-of select="t:OrderID/text()" />
          </orderid>

           <!--Another loop 1 ... -->
          <!--<xsl:for-each select="key('k1',OrderID)[generate-id(.)=generate id(key('k2',concat(OrderID,'|',ItemID)))]">-->
          <!--  <items>-->
          <!--    <item>-->
          <!--      <xsl:value-of select="ItemID" />-->
          <!--    </item>-->

               <!--Another loop 2... -->
          <!--    <xsl:for-each select="key('k2',concat(OrderID,'|',ItemID))[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('k3',concat(OrderID,'|',ItemID,'|',TrackingID)))]">-->
          <!--      <shippingdetails>-->
          <!--        <trackingcode>-->
          <!--          <xsl:value-of select="TrackingID"/>-->
          <!--        </trackingcode>-->
          <!--      </shippingdetails>-->
          <!--    </xsl:for-each>-->

          <!--  </items>-->
          <!--</xsl:for-each>-->


        </order>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </orders>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything or my approach is wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the prefix `t` in all path expressions for all elements from that namespace so `t:level` instead of `level` is the fix you need: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhDDyC/8